# Ajax and Search Engines

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

There is a site with dynamic content loading http://title24.ru/. An example of one of the many pages of the site: http://title24.ru/index/allhyips_en/0-23
All the content of the page is generated using the cURL parser script:

```
<?php
$___notjson=1;
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$a = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$ch = curl_init($a);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$ahtml = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
require ('phpQuery.php');
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($ahtml);
$siteurl = $doc->find('#sitename')->text();
$ch = curl_init('https://'.$siteurl.'/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'boyah!!!!!');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$titleon = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($titleon);
$title = $doc->find('title')->html();
$counttitle = mb_strlen($title, 'utf-8');
//***получаем значения атрибута 'description' - content***
foreach ($doc['meta[name=description]'] as $meta) {
$desc .= pq($meta)->attr('content');
}
$countdesc = mb_strlen($desc, 'utf-8');
//***получаем значения атрибута 'description' - content***
//***получаем значения атрибута 'keywords' - content***
foreach ($doc['meta[name=keywords]'] as $meta) {
$keyw .= pq($meta)->attr('content');
}
$countkeyw = mb_strlen($keyw, 'utf-8');
//***получаем значения атрибута 'keywords' - content***
$internalurls = $doc->find('[href]')->count($internalurls);
$noindexurls = $doc->find('[rel=nofollow]')->count($noindexurls);
$indexurls = $internalurls - $noindexurls;
$ch = curl_init('https://a.pr-cy.ru/'.$siteurl.'/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$ipdnsinfo = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($ipdnsinfo);
$ipadress = $doc->find('#ip .content-test')->html();
$countryadress = $doc->find('#ipCountry .content-test')->html();
$howollddomain = $doc->find('#whoisCreationDate .content-test')->html();
$canceldomain = $doc->find('#whoisExpirationDate .content-test')->html();

echo '<div class="infobox3">';
echo '<div class="ramka"><div class="infobox">Заглавие: <span class="infobox20">' .$title .'&nbsp('.$counttitle .' символов)</span><div class="fldel"></div></div>';
echo '<div class="infobox">Описание: <span class="infobox20">' .$desc .'&nbsp('.$countdesc .' символов)</span><div class="fldel"></div></div>';
echo '<div class="infobox">Ключевые фразы: <span class="infobox20">' .$keyw .'&nbsp('.$countkeyw .' символов)</span><div class="fldel"></div></div>';
echo '<div class="infobox">IP adress: <span class="infobox20">' .$ipadress .'</span><div class="fldel"></div></div>';
echo '<div class="infobox">Страна сервер: <span class="infobox20">' .$countryadress .'</span><div class="fldel"></div></div>';
echo '<div class="infobox">Возраст домена: <span class="infobox20">' .$howollddomain .'</span><div class="fldel"></div></div>';
echo '<div class="infobox">Срок окончания: <span class="infobox20">' .$canceldomain .'</span><div class="fldel"></div></div>';
echo '<div class="infobox">Внутренние ссылки: <span class="infobox20">Найдено ' .$internalurls .' ссылок, из которых индексируются ' .$indexurls .'</span><div class="fldel"></div></div></div>';
echo '</div>';
?>
```

This script is displayed on the html page using jQuery code in  :

```
$.get("/php/titledesc.php?param0=valueA&param1=valueB...&paramN=valueM", function arrr (data) {$("#titledescr").html( $(data).html() )});
```

In the contents of the block:

```
<div id="titledescr"></div>
```

The fact is that the search engines do not see this content, for them this content does not exist, accordingly - it badly affects the ranking of the site in the SERP.

Appeal to you
because I do not know how to solve this problem. If you have a ready solution - help me please in this.

Excuse me for my English, when writing this question, I used Google's translator service. 
If you do not understand something, let me know, I'll try to write something differently.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is, nowdays google sees [dynamic content](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html). If you don't block javascript files in your robots.txt, the crawler will see your dynamic content.

If you have problems with your dynamic content, you should have a look inside the google webmaster tools. They also provide tools to see, how google see's your page.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to my problem. I'm going to work on the solution.